# Unobstructive client validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and I keep getting the following error.

> Validation type names in unobtrusive
>   client validation rules must be
>   unique. The following validation type
>   was seen more than once: number

I have no clue as I have this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Mark)
```

// my viewmodel

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message")]
        [Number(ErrorMessage = "Message")]
        public decimal Mark { get; set; }
```

If I change it from a decimal to string it will not complain. What is going on?

**Edit**

I think it is because of this the          `[Number(ErrorMessage = "Message")]` annotation. I am using this library  [Data annotation extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Numeric/Create)

It seems not not like that I am using decimals. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using type decimal, you do not need to use the [Numeric] attribute because MVC already sees you are using a numeric type and injects that in for you (which is causing the error).  When you change to a string, the [Numeric] is then needed to tell the validation how you want that string to work.

In the next version of DataAnnotationsExtensions, I'll change the [Numeric] attribute so it won't collide with the MVC version in this case.  But for now, removing the [Numeric] attribute will be just fine because [Numeric] on a numeric type is redundant anyway.

Comment: Right totally forgot about that. However I would say that it still would be desirable to be able to do as you have no control over the message generated when binding fails(or at least I don't think you do). It is also only sever side and not client side.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have multiple model validators which are adding the same client rule twice, are you using a custom validatiOn provider?

Comment: I am using a custom validation provider and am getting this error. Why? What can I do? This is the validation provider I am using:[Knoema.Localization.Mvc.ValidationLocalizer](https://github.com/Knoema/Localization/blob/master/Mvc/Mvc/ValidationLocalizer.cs)

Answer (score 0):

`Required` will become duplicate since `Mark` is not nullable. I would change it to be `decimal?`