# MVC3 - complex model, properties have same field name, unable to render model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

I need help in rendering a complex model.

I have a complex model with 2 class properties. All 3 classes (AddProjectQnrModel, ProjectModel, QTModel) have GroupId and GroupName properties.

```
public class AddProjectQnrModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        public ProjectModel Project { get; set; }

        public QCTModel QCT { get; set; }
    }
```

In the view I am using editor templates :

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Project, "_EditProject.cshtml")
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.QCT, "_QCT-v1.cshtml")
```

I cannot use @html.Partial as it will not bind the properties correctly, so I have to use editor templates.

On running the project I get this error:

> Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be
>   unique. The following validation type was seen more than once:
>   required
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Validation type
>   names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The
>   following validation type was seen more than once: required

```
Source Error: 

Line 26: 
Line 27:         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Project, "_EditProject.cshtml")
Line 28: 
Line 29:
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you've run into something similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784662/368296).

**MVC will automatically add a Required validation for `GroupId` because `int` is not a nullable type**. When you add an explicit specification of `[Required]`, the validation is duplicated and results in your error. Remove the explicit `[Required]` attribute for any properties that are inherently not nullable and things should work as you expect.

**Alternatively, if you want to prevent the automatic generation** in favor of the explicit `[Required]` declarations, you can add the following to `Application_Start` as seen on this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4845768/368296):

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false
```